# Ionic 1 WkWebView iOS - Failed to load resource: Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cors, wkwebview

**1. Short Intro**

recently we've updated our application just to be compliant with new Apple's rules about Apple signing flow, but wasn't enough.

Apple blocks our release base on the fact that we do not currently adopt the new web view WkWebView.

So we decide to use the following plugin: < cordova-plugin-ionic-webview > ( https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview )

It was too wonderful to see that problems with XHR file:// request was fixed by new versions BUT an important CORS block is still present.

**2. Problem**

As the title says, every call that we perform to our server still continue to receive the error " Failed to load resource: Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow ... "

**3. What we've done**

Reading aware, we add into our server configuration (web.xml) the following filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And in our config.xml as guides describe, we add:

```
<allow-navigation href="ionic://localhost/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost*"/>
<content src="index.html" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

But the problem is still present.

**4. Environment versioning**

- iOS 13.3
- Cordova 7.1.0
- Ionic v1
- Angular 1.5

So how to allow the application to pull data from our server ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter), this `web.xml` config will not work:

> The above configuration enables the filter but does not relax the cross-origin policy. As a minimum, you will need to add a `cors.allowed.origins` initialisation parameter as described below to enable cross-origin requests.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost, ionic://ionic</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The docs also have `url-pattern` set to `/*` and not `*`, but I'm not sure if that's important.

You might have to add more configuration depending on what types of requests your app makes.

Comment: Hi Thomas, and thanks for answer. 
I try to put that kind of configuration, but problem is still present :( 

So maybe it doesn't depend on the server configuration (only) BUT, that param afterward is needed server-side. 

Simon